# Print a sequence of n numbers

Tags: haskell, io

I have a simple function that takes an Integer n and return a string representing the array from 1..n.

```
nthLine :: Integer -> String
nthLine n = intercalate " " $ map show [1..n]
```

The main function takes input n from the user and prints the nthLine out to screen:

```
getInteger :: String -> Integer      # This seems redundant
getInteger xs = (read xs)::Integer 

nthLineStr :: String  -> String      # And so does this function
nthLineStr xs = nthLine (getInteger xs )

main = do line <- fmap nthLineStr getLine
          putStrLn line
```

Any tips on how this may be simplified/made better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `unwords` in place of `intercalate " "`.

Given the type signature of `getInteger :: String -> Integer` the return type of `read xs` *must* be `Integer` in order for the type system to unify what you've written, making your type annotation on the function implementation there redundant. You can perform eta-reduction on `getInteger` then (that is, write it in pointfree style) and drop the `xs` for an implementation of—

```
getInteger :: String -> Integer
getInteger = read
```

This is now obviously a specialization of `read`, which isn't all that interesting. Look now to the implementation of `nthLineStr` where you can see that the result of `getInteger xs` is passed to `nthLine`. Because the type of `nthLine` is given as `Integer -> String`, the compiler can again determine that `read` *must* return an Integer if you change the definition of `nthLineStr` to—

```
nthLineStr :: String -> String
nthLineStr xs = nthLine (read xs)
```

You can perform eta-reduction again to write `nthLineStr` as `nthLineStr = nthLine . read`. `nthLineStr` is a bit of a kludge though, in that it muddies the waters between your pure code and the outside world. Keep your (de-)serialization functions apart from the rest of your program, it shouldn't matter to the core logic of your application whether you were passed a `String` or a `Text` value or length encoded sequence of unit values (`[()]`).

```
main :: IO ()
main = do n <- fmap read getLine
       putStrLn $ nthLine n
```

Or you could use another `Prelude` function, `interact :: (String -> String) -> IO ()` (a useful concept, but note this changes the semantics a bit).

```
main :: IO ()
main = interact (nthLine . read)
```

Comment: One last question; does eta-reduction always imply converting something in pointful style to point-free?

Comment: In a Haskell context often yes, but it can also refer to an optimization operation the compiler performs. See [Eta conversion - HaskellWiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Eta_conversion) for a few more words on the topic (a very few).